# require('readLine') in JavaScript showing error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Pls. can anyone help on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJcK0.png)

What is that two dots under require? and its not showing output result?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHz7w.png)

When trying to type in the output terminal, its not typing anything?

Thanks.

I am trying this code today and i could not give the user input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

When you bring your cursor to dots you can see message like this:

`File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.`

You can either use `Quick Fix` or change your import like this:

```
import readline from "readline";
```

Also, do not forget to add `"type": "module",` to your `package.json`

**Edit**

In your code you imported `readline` as `rLine` but while you are creating interface you used it as `readline.createInterface()` you should update your code like this:

```
import readline from "readline";

var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

rl.question("What is your name?\n", (answer) => {
  console.log(answer);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that one and the code is running. But may i know why i could not give the input from the input terminal?

Comment: I edited my answer and added the working code. Take a look at it and let me know if it helped.